# Find wordpress/buddypress unknown sub url

Tags: wordpress, url, curl, buddypress

I need to automate the download of user data and shared files from a wordpress site that use buddypress.

The solution using `curl` proposed by [the @antics's gist](https://gist.github.com/antics/4079584) seems to adress all my requirements.

The problem is that I can't locate the exact URL of the login page `*/wp-login.php`. There is no way to retrieve PHP files from an apache server and - even if I scrap the whole public part of the web site - I can't find any information about this specific URL.

How could I find this unknown URL `*/wp-login.php` and which command line tool could I use to do that?

Any other cli solution to my problem is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It is in general will be redirected to the the root directory where the site is hosted. So if your site is www.example.com, it can be access at `www.example.com/wp-login.php`. For local server, it depends on how your root directory is configured. Either at `http://localhost/wp-login.php` (if it is directly installed at the root directory) or `http://localhost/folder/wp-login.php` (if it is within a directory of the root).

Comment: I don't know the file structure... I'm a user, not a system manager.

Comment: In fact, your answer is true in many cases but it does't not work for me and it doesn't really answer the question. I found *manually* that the login URL is ````www.example.com/intranet/connection/````. I'm interested to know how to achieve it with a script.